# No O/P on console using System.Out.Println while running Hadoop job in Eclipse

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

While running the Map Reduce Program in Eclipse, I am not able to see the output in console using `System.out.println`. Can anyone please let me know what can be done regarding it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your program runs fully ? Is it totally blank or your get atleast any result ? How are you running your program ?

Comment: Please, add the information that @Jay asks, as well as a small snippet of your code, in which the `print` command appears. Is it inside an `if` block, or a loop? Then, maybe these commands are never reached...

Comment: After your suggestion i checked the code with breakpoints so i came to know it was never reaching the condition due to data mismatch. Got the output successfully.

Comment: @Vefthym, can you please respond the same as answer so that i can accept it and close the question

Comment: @PiyushJindal Ok, I added it as an answer. I'm glad that I helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, add the information that @Jay asks, as well as a small snippet of your code, in which the print command appears. Is it inside an if block, or a loop? Then, maybe these commands are never reached...